# Client Callable Firebase Function fails when deployed to regions other than us-central1

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Client Callable Firebase Function fails with "Error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." when deployed to regions other than us-central1 (tried Europe West and Asia).

**Server Code**

```
exports.getName = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall((data, context) => {
     return { name: "Testopoulos" };
});
```

**Client Code** ([React Native Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/functions/reference/functions))

```
const httpsCallableUserName = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getName');

getUserName = () => {
    httpsCallableUserName()
    .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data.name);
    })
    .catch(httpsError => {
        console.log(httpsError); 
    })
  }
```

There is a note in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client_callable_functions) saying that "[when] using HTTP functions to serve dynamic content for hosting, you must use us-central1" but I am just returning an object to our frontend React Native client and not using Firebase Hosting. I read other posts about the regions but I don't think it is the same case. Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to also show the client code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DougStevenson I have added the client code.

Comment: Try `return { data : { name : "Testopulous" } }; ` to make sure that the return value is being correctly wrapped when sent to the client.

Comment: @JamesPoag the same result. In any case, it would had been weird if it had worked because it works fine for us-central1 with only the {name: "value"}.

Comment: Did you note in the doc that "the client can also specify a region, **and must do so if the function runs in any region other than us-central1.**", see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client_callable_functions

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thanks for pointing that out! It sounds promising but following that doc does not seem to work as doing `var functions = firebase.functions('europe-west1');` returns `Firebase: firebase.functions() takes either no argument or a Firebase App instance. (app/invalid-app-argument).`.

Comment: @Va5ili5 Yes... I encountered the same problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787147/exception-firebase-functions-takes-no-argument-when-specifying-a-reg

Comment: @RenaudTarnec we made some progress by figuring out that instead of `firebase.initializeApp(config); var functions = firebase.functions('europe-west1');` you have to do `var functions = firebase.initializeApp(config).functions('europe-west1');` instead. Now we moved passed that error to face a 500 response. What about yours?

Comment: @Va5ili5 Brilliant! Where did you find this syntax?! It works correctly in my case too. Please add an answer to my post and I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec awesome! My colleague will respond to your question so please accept that since he figured it out. Please add your answer here too about the client having to specify the region and I will accept it.

Comment: Figured out the 500s too :))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client_callable_functions) "the client can also specify a region, and **must do so if the function runs in any region other than `us-central1`**.".

As you have found (see comments above), it has to be done with:

```
var functions = firebase.initializeApp(config).functions('europe-west1');
```

Answer (score 0):

IN 2023 Firebase 10 it's slightly different

```
initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const functions = getFunctions();
functions.region = 'europe-west3';
```

works for me :-)