# Exception "firebase.functions() takes ... no argument ..." when specifying a region for a Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am following the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client_callable_functions) in order to call, from a web page, a Callable Function located in a different region than `us-central1`.

More precisely, in the web page, I do `var functions = firebase.functions('europe-west1');` but I get the following error and no result from the call:

```
uncaught exception: functions: Firebase: firebase.functions() takes either no argument or a Firebase App instance. (app/invalid-app-argument).
```

Here is the MCV code:

**Cloud Function**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.getName = functions
  .region('europe-west1')
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return { name: 'MyName' };
  });
```

**Web Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxx",
            authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxx",
            databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxx",
            projectId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
            storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxx",
            messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);   

        var functions = firebase.functions('europe-west1');

        var getName = functions.httpsCallable('getName');
        getName().then(function (result) {
            console.log((result.data));
        }).catch(function (error) {
            // Getting the Error details.
            var code = error.code;
            var message = error.message;
            var details = error.details;
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I run the same code in the `us-central1` region (calling `firebase.functions()` without argument) it works correctly.

**Cloud Function (`us-central1` version)**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.getName = functions  
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return { name: 'MyName' };
  });
```

**Web Page (`us-central1` version)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
.....

<body>
    <script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
             .....
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var functions = firebase.functions();

        ...    

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that I've updated my dev environment to the latest versions of `firebase-functions`, `firebase-admin` and `firebase-tools`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By trial and error I found that you have to do it like this:

```
var config = {
            apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxx",
            authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxx",
            databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxx",
            projectId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
            storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxx",
            messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
        };
var fireApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
var functions = fireApp.functions('europe-west1');
```

Comment: This is already documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations

Comment: @DougStevenson If I may, the documentation seems to be wrong or uncomplete. Have a look at the question and the MCV code which implements what is said in the documentation, i.e. `var functions = firebase.functions('europe-west1');` and gives an error.

Comment: It's sitting right there in the docs under the heading "Client-side location selection for callable functions".  Switch to the "web" tab to see the code: `var functions = firebase.functions('us-central1');`

Comment: What I am saying is that if you do `firebase.initializeApp(config); var functions = firebase.functions('xxxx');` it doesn't work. It would probably be better if the doc is adapted as per the response, since we were at least two to make the mistake.

Comment: npm install -g firebase-tools@latest ; npm install firebase-functions@latest ; npm install firebase-admin@latest

Comment: const app = express(); /* ...routing stuff... */ export const api = functions.region('europe-west1').runWith({ memory: '1GB', timeoutSeconds: 60 }).https.onRequest(app);

Answer (score 3):

the official way to do that is:

```
var functions = firebase.app().functions('europe-west1');
```

as mentioned in the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations

Comment: Yes indeed. Thx. Actually at the time of writing the question and answer the documentation was wrong.

Comment: why the need of the '.app()', so that is the way ?

Comment: For some reason I had project that this way worked but in another project only worked like this:
var functions = firebase.apps[0].functions('europe-west1')