# Cannot deploy firebase cloud functions on 'specific region'?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I cannot deploy my firebase cloud functions to specific region. This is my code.

```
exports.helloWorld1 = functions.region('asia-northeast1').https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

exports.helloWorld2 = functions.region('us-central1').https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

exports.helloWorld3 = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

exports.helloWorld4 = functions.region('us-east1').https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Then I ran deploying the code. This is the result.

[image]

How could I define cloud functions' region correctly?

This case is different from [use region other than us-central1 for Google Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902502/use-region-other-than-us-central1-for-google-cloud-functions) because these functions are deploying on Firebase CLI, not general function executed from gcloud.

#

I found important information.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client_callable_functions

### Important: If you are using HTTP functions to serve dynamic content for hosting, you must use us-central1.

Comment: What version of the Firebase CLI did you deploy with? Make sure it's the latest and try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use region other than us-central1 for Google Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902502/use-region-other-than-us-central1-for-google-cloud-functions)

Comment: here's also explained, how to migrate existing Cloud Functions in between regions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions

Comment: @MichaelBleigh I updated firebase, firebase-admin to the latest version. But the problem is still persist.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I followed them. Not only try changing from one to another regions. But also try specify region at firstly creating a function. Both cases I cannot deploy functions on specific location.

Comment: @Kittipat `functions.region('europe-west1')` defines where the function shall run, not neccessarily where it had been deployed to, in case I understand the documentation correctly. install `firebase-tools` with `npm install -g firebase-tools` if you want to deploy elsewhere.

Comment: Did you previously have versions of helloWorld1 and helloWorld3 that were deployed in the us-central1 region?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec No, all functions were deployed at first time. And that is all the code for test. I just added const functions = require('firebase-functions'); on the top of code.

Comment: I'm not sure this may be the reason. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client_callable_functions 

"Important: If you are using HTTP functions to serve dynamic content for hosting, you must use us-central1."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51772057/client-callable-firebase-function-fails-when-deployed-to-regions-other-than-us-c